# Communication between Android apps on separate devices

Tags: android, ios

What is the recommended way to communicate between two apps, each running on a different device (assume a mix of devices between Android and iOS)?

I was just looking for a generalized discussion of best practices for an app to communicate between iOS and Android devices (think a interactive, real time game).

I am working on an app idea.  I would like prototype having an iOS and Android app communicating with each other and wanted feedback about what approaches are viable.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details, such as the number of devices in communication, the distance between the devices, the size/type of data being communicated, whether you are aiming for peer-to-peer or something server-based, etc. What you are asking is akin to asking "what is the recommended way to communicate between two people", and, as with that, the details matter.

Comment: it was just a generic question.  I really haven't thought about it beyond that. I was looking for something to learn about android development and that was the thought I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Nearby from Google,

- It allows you to communicate between iOS and Android
- It is recommended for realtime interactions (e.g. multiplayer game)

Link: https://developers.google.com/nearby/

Comment: Nearby Messages is available in iOS which has got some delay in transferring the data. Nearby Connections is not available in iOS which work like charm in android.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a service such as [Parse](http://parse.com) which helps you a lot to handle the communication of your app between devices.